# BootStrap Modal is refreshed on KeyPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bootstrap-4

I know there are question asked before, but I have tried the solution but it's not working. I have split the component differently but then also it refresh on every single keypress.

```
const TenementRegistration = () => {

   const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
   const [name, setName] = useState("");
   const [editId, setEditId] = useState("");
    
    function Example() {

  

    const onSubmitHandler = async () => {
      
      const data = {
        name: name
      }
      await services.postService("User", data).then((res) => {
              onGetUserData();
      });
    }

    return(

        <Modal
          show={show}
          onHide={() => setShow(false)}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
          scrollable="true"
          centered
          animation="true"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
              Add User
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div className="form-container">
              <form>
                <Row>
                  <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6 
                  center">
                    <label for="inputName" className="asy- 
                    FormLabel">
                      Name
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control asy-InputValues"
                      id="policyName"
                      placeholder="Enter Property Id"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setName(e.target.value);
                      }}
                      value={name}
                      required
                    />
                   </div>
                 </Row>
              </form>
            </div>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="submit-button"
              onClick={() => {
                onSubmitHandler();
              }}
            >
             Submit
            </button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>

       const [data, setData] = useState([]);

       useEffect(() => {
        onGetUserData();
       }, []);

       const onGetUserData = async () => {
           services.getService("User").then((res) => {
               setData(res.data);
           });
       };

       const onEditData = async (id) => {
          setShow(true);
          const newData = data.filter((obj) => obj.id === id)[0];
          setName(newData.name);
      }
     //Table where we show name and pass id to update button
}
```

I have also tried to Split the Modal and separate the form (not in this example) but it didn't work any suggestions how to handle the modal problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your button onClick

```
<button
              type="button"
              className="submit-button"
              onClick={(event) => 

    {
              
    
          onSubmitHandler(event);
                  }}
                >
                  Submit
            </button>
```

then in that function:

```
 const onSubmitHandler = async (event) => {

      event.preventDefault()
      
      const data = {
        name: name
    }
     await services.postService("User", data).then((res) => {
              onGetUserData();
            });
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work , Thank's.

Comment: Is the bootstrap modal refreshed on submitting the form or refreshed irrespective of any key press?

Comment: It's refreshing every time on keypress (not on submitting)